# Converting from fread() to sql field contents

Tags: php, string, arrays, fread

I have a block of code which I am trying to move from a file based system to blobs stored in the database, however I am having a difficult time locating the equivalent string based methods to the `fread()` methods.

The code I am trying to convert is as follows :

```
$max_codewords_array=array(0,26,44,70,100,134,172,196,242,292,346,404,466,532,581,655,733,815,901,991,1085,1156, 1258,1364,1474,1588,1706,1828,1921,2051,2185,2323,2465,2611,2761,2876,3034,3196,3362,3532,3706);
$max_codewords=$max_codewords_array[$this->qrcode_version];
$max_modules_1side=17+($this->qrcode_version <<2);
$matrix_remain_bit=array(0,0,7,7,7,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0);

/* ---- read version ECC data file */
$byte_num=$matrix_remain_bit[$this->qrcode_version]+($max_codewords << 3);
$filename=QRCODE_DATA_PATH."/qrv".$this->qrcode_version."_".$ec.".dat";

$fp1 = fopen ($filename, "rb");
$matx=fread($fp1,$byte_num);
$maty=fread($fp1,$byte_num);
$masks=fread($fp1,$byte_num);
$fi_x=fread($fp1,15);
$fi_y=fread($fp1,15);
$rs_ecc_codewords=ord(fread($fp1,1));
$rso=fread($fp1,128);
fclose($fp1);
```

I have the data stored in the database as `bin2hex ( gzencode( str ) )` in the field named 'Data', and have no problems reading this data back out into a variable as follows :

```
$data = gzdecode(hex2bin($field['Data']));
```

However when it comes to the `fread()` section, I am not sure how to swap all those commands in a way that is also binary safe.  (aka, the new `$data` value contains the entire file contents that `fread()` normally chunks through)

Following is the code I wish to replace `fread()` with the equivalent binary safe string method, and instead of the `$fp1` file handle, use the contents stored in `$data` (as mentioned above).

```
$matx=fread($fp1,$byte_num);
$maty=fread($fp1,$byte_num);
$masks=fread($fp1,$byte_num);
$fi_x=fread($fp1,15);
$fi_y=fread($fp1,15);
$rs_ecc_codewords=ord(fread($fp1,1));
$rso=fread($fp1,128);
```

(While waiting on an answer, I wrote this solution which works)

**String reader class**

```
class sread {
    static $position = 0;
    static $data;

    public static function open($data) {
        self::$data = $data;
    }

    public static function read($bytes) {
        if( (self::$position + $bytes ) >= strlen(self::$data) ) {
            $data = substr(self::$data, self::$position);
        } else {
            $data = substr(self::$data, self::$position, $bytes);
        }
        self::$position = self::$position + strlen($data);
        return $data;
    }

    public static function close() {
        self::$data = null;
        self::$position = 0;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
$data = ""; // the long string containing the data you wish to move through

sread::open($data);
$matx = sread::read($byte_num);
$maty = sread::read($byte_num);
$masks = sread::read($byte_num);
$f1_x = sread::read(15);
$f1_y = sread::read(15);
$rs_ecc_codewords = ord(sread::read(1));
$rso = sread::read(128);
sread::close();
```

This is a very rough example, however feel free to expand on it. Barmars solution does the same thing, however this class handles the byte increment for you and is almost the same syntax for a drop-in replacement for `fread()`. Accepting Barmars solution :)

Comment: Use `substr()` to extract substrings of `$data`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to store each value as a separate column, instead of encoding it as a blob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `substr`, and use a variable to keep track of the current position as you go through the data.

```
$curpos = 0;
$matx = substr($data, $curpos, $byte_num);
$curpos += $byte_num;
$maty = substr($data, $curpos, $byte_num);
$curpos += $byte_num;
$masks = substr($data, $curpos, $byte_num);
$curpos += $byte_num;
$fi_x = substr($data, $curpos, 15);
$curpos += 15;
$fi_y = substr($data, $curpos, 15);
$curpos += 15;
$rs_ecc_codewords = ord(substr($data, $curpos, 1));
$curpos += 1;
$rso = substr($data, $curpos, 128);
```

Another way would be with a regular expression to extract each part as a capture group:

```
$regex = "/(.{$byte_num})(.{$byte_num})(.{$byte_num})(.{15})(.{15})(.)(.{128})/";
preg_match($regex, $data, $match);
list ($ignore, $matx, $maty, $masks, $fi_x, $fi_y, $rs_ecc_char, $rso) = $match;
$rss_ecc_codewords = ord($rss_ecc_char);
```

Comment: While you were writing this, I was doing something similar in the form of a class I could wrap around and drop in anywhere (pretty much)  `fopen`, `fread`, `fclose` are located when swapping to work with the data as a string instead of a file resource.  The regex syntax, I am not sure how that would work on binary data, but after some digging `substr` seemed to be more flexible than `mb_substr`.  Thank you for the reply :)

Comment: For binary data, take a look at `unpack()`.